# what are the .lib files used by link.exe?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I encountered a build issue with visual studio's 'link.exe' tool, and at some point, which I would have normally investigated by passing my build command as an argument to linux's `strace -efile` tool to get a dump of all the files considered by the linker, which couldn't be found and which were selected. But of course, we're on Windows this time, and `strace` is not an option.

- the problem was indeed the linker picking the wrong file when I said `ntoskrnl.lib` on the command line
- the root cause was an invalid `%LIB%` contents that wasn't matching the include paths passed to `cl.exe` calls

**Question:** how could I force link.exe to reveal the full path of the files it is linking (including .lib) ? (and save myself this hassle next time)

Comment: **NOTE:** I'd prefer to stick to tools available in visual studio or mingw32 package repository. I'm aware of some attempts to rebuild an strace-like tool for windows, but none that seem to have been community-reviewed to the point I can install them on this machine.

Comment: Try [`/VERBOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/verbose-print-progress-messages) option. Also, [Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) includes tools that can watch files opened by a process, among many other things.

Comment: @igorTandetnik: thanks for the /VERBOSE trick: it would be accepted if it had been an anwser. Can you be more specific about which of Sysinternals you use to track file operations ?

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)